# filter select boxes based on value given with default value of none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work on this project that user select there "region" and data belong or related to that region will be listed on the next "select box" called "city", I manage to workout the region and the city, it's working with the helped of this community here, and I'm so thankful.

my problem is, if I select specific city, data belong to that city must be on the list of barangay.

one thing before i forget, if the region is empty, the list of city must not display.

in case you need a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/4c923p6u/4/)

html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<p>SELECT YOUR THE REGION
<select type="text" value="" id="region">
<option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
<option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
<option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
</select></p><br><br> 

<p>SELECT YOUR THE CITY
<select type="text" name="city" id="city">
<option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>

<option value="DavaoOriental" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
<option value="CompostelaValey" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
<option value="DavaoOriental" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
</select></p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE BARANGAY
<select type="text" id="brgy">
<option value="">Barangay</option>
<option value="Baganga">Baculin</option>
<option value="Baganga">Batawan</option>
<option value="Baganga">Batiano</option>
<option value="Baganga">Binondo</option>
<option value="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
<option value="Baganga">Campawan</option>
<option value="Baganga">Central</option>
<option value="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
<option value="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
<option value="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
<option value="Baganga">Lucod</option>
<option value="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
<option value="Baganga">Mikit</option>
<option value="MatiCity">Central</option>
<option value="MatiCity">Badas</option>
<option value="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
<option value="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
</select></p><br><br>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#region").change(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    $("#city option").hide();
        $("#city").val("");
    $("#city option[value='"+val+"']").show();
  $("#city").change();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the same hiding logic and used the `id` as value to filter the options:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#city").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).find(":selected").prop("id");
    $("#brgy option").hide();
    $("#brgy").val("");
    $("#brgy option[value='" + val + "']").show();
  });
  $("#region").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#city option").hide();
    $("#city").val("");
    $("#city option[value='" + val + "']").show();
    $("#city").change();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>SELECT YOUR THE REGION
  <select type="text" value="" id="region">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE CITY
  <select type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>

    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
    <option value="CompostelaValey" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
    <option value="DavaoOriental" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>

<p>SELECT YOUR THE BARANGAY
  <select type="text" id="brgy">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Baculin</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Batiano</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Binondo</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Campawan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Central</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Lucod</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
    <option value="Baganga">Mikit</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Central</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Badas</option>
    <option value="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
    <option value="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
  </select>
</p><br><br>
```

Comment: thank you very much solved my problem your my savior